# Questions about game editors - Arqade or GameDev.SE?

Tags: discussion

Recently I had a bunch of questions regarding usage of the galaxy editor, a tool for Starcraft 2.
Since there is both [Starcraft 2] and [Galaxy Editor] tags here, I went asking here right away.

To my surprise, I now have one of the questions put as "off-topic" with a direction to go to GameDev.SE instead ([Custom variables/fields for units?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192562/custom-variables-fields-for-units)). The problem is, on their site there is no [Galaxy Editor] section at all, and [Starcraft] is hardly ever used as well.

Seems to me, that GameDev.SE is more about game development in general, rather than the usage of particular tools shipped with a game. If there is a question about adding a specific SC2 trigger, or modifying a SC2 data field in the Galaxy Editor - is it a generic game development question?
I expect getting an answer here more likely...

On the other hand, if questions about modding are forbidden here - that almost completely defeats the purpose of the [Galaxy Editor], as its sole purpose is to create custom maps and mods.

So my question is:

- Here or there? Why here or not here?
- If not here, shouldn't all [Galaxy Editor] questions be actually moved there? Otherwise, I fear we actually split the editor community in half...
- How about other game editors?

Comment: If a question is on topic on one site, it doesn't mean that it's off topic on other sites. It would be perfectly valid to say that the question is on topic on both sites. And we only govern what's on topic on this site. Whatever we decide about the on-topicness of [Galaxy Editor], the Game Dev community should make their own decision, independent of ours.

Comment: [Galaxy Editor] and the link to the question points to *this* site. There is no such tag on GameDev.

Comment: Just to be clear - I am asking about the policy of Arqade, not GameDev